# Check whether an image file exists in a directory or not using PHP

Tags: php, image, file-exists

I have image files in a directory which have downloaded from several resources.

If I have the name of an image, how can I check its existence using PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

Comment: file exists sound intuitive, but it also returns true if you feed it a directory name...

Comment: True, but very few people will give directories an extension of .gif or .jpg or .png; and most people checking for the existence of an image file will be testing against something with one or other of those extensions

Answer (score 7):

`is_file()` checks whether the file exists.

EDIT:
btw, getImageSize() tells you a lot about the image, if it is
valid, parseable by your server, how big it is, what type of image,
etc.
It is said to be slower than some of the more specialized functions,
but when this returns true, you can be sure that the image will be
fully usable.

Comment: guess I should have provided a link as well ;))

Comment: AndreasT: Same thing counts for you ;) http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php and http://php.net/manual/de/function.getimagesize.php. I support the use of getImageSize.